# How long does it take to install Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 after an upgrade t Ubuntu 13.10(13.10 not compatible with Zend Server/Apache 2.2)

It seems after the 'preparing to install screen the installation just sitting there, nothing happens" but busy indicator spinning... no error msg??